# Java Upload Image

Tags: java, image, io, upload, buffer

This is my first post in stackoverflow :D

Sorry for my english (I am italian)

So I have a method called setFrame

```
public static void setFrame()
{
    JFrame GameMain = new JFrame();
    GameMain.setSize(width, high);
    GameMain.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    GameMain.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe!");
    GameMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Grid grid = new Grid(600, 600);
    GameMain.add(grid);
    GameMain.pack();
    GameMain.setVisible(true);


}
```

And this is the class Grid

```
public class Grid
{

private static int high;
private static int width;
public Grid(int width, int high)
{
    width = width;
    high = high;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("/grids/griglia1.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}
```

}

Ok so the problem is that when in the method setFrame I write "GameMain.add(grid);"
The console gives me an error like
"The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Grid)"

Thanks for helping

Comment: unrelated. Please follow these: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: why do you want to add grid? Grid isn't a Swing Component is just a object

Comment: Grid is not a component of Swing, you must extend any of the swing component to add it in swing container like `JFrame`. As far I seen your code you want to add a background image in your `JFrame`. Just add this snippet `frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("path of your image")));`

Comment: i just want to add a grid because i am making tic tac toe

Comment: ok I have solved alone thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you would like to add an image to the JFrame. However, there are a few things wrong with your implementation. First of all, you cannot add images directly to a component. You need to encapsulate them in a JLabel. Additionally, the reason why you cannot add the grid class to your JFrame is because it isn't a swing component.

The easiest way to accomplish what you are trying to do would be to make a JPanel and then add it to the frame, and then make a JLabel that encapsulates your image and add that to the JPanel.

```
public static void setFrame()
{
    JFrame GameMain = new JFrame();
    GameMain.setSize(width, high);
    GameMain.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    GameMain.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe!");
    GameMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel GamePanel = new JPanel();
    GamePanel.setSize(width, high);
    GameMain.add(GamePanel);
    background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/grids/griglia1.png"))));
    GamePanel.add(background);
    GameMain.pack();
    GameMain.setVisible(true);
}
```

This way you can bypass the Grid class altogether. Hope this helps.